# Why the frequent use of “Bad” in German place names (and does it mean something different than “bath”)?

Tags: meaning-in-context, place-name

*Bad* seems to be a frequent component of German place names (e.g. Bad Bergzabern, Bad Doberan, Bad Schandau ...)  Why is this, and what is the meaning of *Bad* in this context?

Comment: Looking up *Bad* in a dictionary would have answered the question. See e.g. http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Bad, meaning Number 3.

Answer (score 31):

The German "Bad" corresponds to the [English "Spa"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spa_town). Towns containing a "Heilbad" may carry the protected title "Bad" and [many of them do](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_spa_towns_in_Germany).

Comment: Fun fact: The German city Aachen used to be called Bad Aachen, until they removed the "Bad" from their name. People claim/joke that this was done so that Aachen will be the first city in any alphabetically ordered list.

Comment: And indeed the English town *Bath* is for the same reason.

Comment: @DirkLiebhold Which helps a lot, but not all the way, because [Aalen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aalen) has a [license plate city code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vehicle_registration_plates_of_Germany) of `AA` which precedes `AC` of Aachen. Just saying (Greetings from Aachen)

Comment: @MartinHennings of course you cannot beet Augsburg on the license plate. ;)

Comment: @JonHanna Not to mention Leamington Spa and Matlock Bath.

Answer (score 24):

German towns can participate in a certification process to allow to carry a rating as *Bad* in their town name.

By German federal law strict [prerequisites](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heilbad) have to be met by an applicant, e.g.:

- presence of certain scientifically proven healing substances in the soil (like minerals, salts, radiation or the like)
- regularly analyzed healthy climate
- institutions that offer certain therapies or wellness facilities
- some characteristics usually found in these towns (e.g. a town hall, parks)
- scientifically acknowledged therapies and medical doctors who offer these treatments

So in summary a town prefixed by *Bad* is a certified spa.

Comment: Does that mean a town can also lose the right to use "Bad" as a part of its name? Has it happened?

Comment: This is one of the most German things I have ever read. :)

Comment: @Beta - not sure about that. I believe once granted it becomes an integral part of the name, hence is forever (which is not the case for the terms *Kurort*, *Lufkurort* etc.) - a now urban district of Stuttgart still is called *Bad Cannstatt*.

Comment: @Takkat as far as I know, Bad Cannstatt still offers some therapy and there was a fountain which carried certain minerals there. So it should be a certified spa. And here is an article about a city that might lose its title: https://www.morgenpost.de/brandenburg-aktuell/article121268341/Bad-Freienwalde-koennte-bald-den-Titel-Bad-verlieren.html

Comment: @Armin; yes, there still is a famous spa there but it is no longer an own town ;)

Comment: @Takkat ok, then this one http://www.general-anzeiger-bonn.de/region/ahr-und-rhein/mehr-ahr-und-rhein/Bad-Bodendorf-verliert-Heilbad-Titel-article1077493.html Now I've read a bit more and they didn't fulfill the requirements anymore...

Comment: @Armin good to know - so it really is a valid certificate.

Answer (score 13):

You asked only about Germany, and [TimWolla's answer](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/38806/1487) is also correct for Austria, but not for Switzerland. (These are the three biggest countries where German is an official language.)

The reason, why this is different in different countries, is, because this is a matter of statutory provisions, which are different from nation to nation. To put *»Bad«* in front of the name of a town has similarities to *»Dr.«* as part of a persons name.

The word *Bad* means *bath, spa*.

In Detail:

In **Germany** such towns may call themselves *»Bad«*, which contain a medical spa, that is approved by the national authorities. It also has to have the legal state of a *»Stadt«* (*city*).

In **Austria**, it's not the national authorities who decide which town may carry this title, but the states authorities (Austria has 9 states, Germany has 16 states), and they do it for medical spas, thermal baths and air spas. So you can find towns in Austria, which contain the word *»Bad«* in their name, but which just have fresh air, but no bath (i.e. no water spa). An example for such a town is *Bad Goisern*, which lays close to *Bad Ischl* and *Bad Aussee*, who both have conventional spas, while there is no conventional spa (but just fresh air) in Bad Goisern.

In Austria a *Bad* doesn't need to have the legal state of a *»Stadt«*. Bad Goisern, for example, is not a *Stadt* (*city*), it's just a *Marktgemeinde* (*market community*).

Italy (*»Terme«*), France (*»les-Bains«*), Poland (*»Zdrój«*) and Serbia (*»banja«*) have similar regulations for town-titles that refer to spas (which in all four nations stand behind the town's name). But German is not an official language in any of these nations, so there in no *Bad* in any other nation but Germany and Austria. (One exception is Südtirol, which is a part of Italy. German is an official language in this part of Italy, but city names are created there according to Italian laws, and so there is no *Bad* in Südtirol.)

German also has the state of an official language in Switzerland, Liechtenstein, Luxembourg and Belgium, but non of these nations has regulations for town-titles of spas, so no town in those countries contain the word *»Bad«* in their name.

---

**Bad Fucking**

pronunciation: [baːd ˈfʊkɪŋ] (rhymes to *"hard booking"* in non-rhotic accents, i.e. when the *r* in *hard* is silent)

In Austria, there is a little village called [Fucking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fucking,_Austria), who's name accidentally is written identically to the progressive form of a famous English verb (but it is pronounced differently). Because of this accidentally similarity, the Austrian Author Kurt Palm wrote a novel named »Bad Fucking« in 2010, and in 2013 the Austrian movie director Harald Sicheritz made a movie (a comedy) with the same title out of this book:

[image: Bad Fucking]

But while the little village *Fucking* really exists, *Bad Fucking* is just a fictional place, and the part *Bad* refers to the fact, that this fictional village is an air spa (i.e. has fresh air).

Comment: Auch in Deutschland ist es Landesrecht, nicht Bundesrecht. Der Kinofilm, der hier  die Hälfte Deines Antwortvolumens und durch das Bild den Löwnanteil der Bandbreite dieser gesamten Q&A ausmacht, mag zwar witzig sein, beantwortet die Frage aber nicht wirklich.

Comment: ...und in Deutschland ist der Städtebeinamen "Bad" auch nicht automatisch (hauptsächlich) mit Wasser verbunden (auch wenn heutzutage fast jede Stadt wenigstens ein Schwimm*bad* hat.) - Bad Reichenhall z.B. wird jetzt nicht in erster Linie mit Plantschen verbunden, sondern mit Luft, die Stadt Bad Oldesloe ist gar kein Heilbad und hat den "Titel" nur im Namen.

Comment: "Bad" kann auch hintergestellt sein, wie z.B. in Karlsbad/Karlovy Vary in Böhmen

Comment: Und *Bad* ist nicht an das Stadtrecht geknüpft, wie zum Beispiel der [Markt Bad Hindelang](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bad_Hindelang) im Allgäu zeigt.

Comment: Und Aachen dürfte ein "Bad" tragen, verzichtet aber darauf, weil sie sonst nicht so weit vorne im Alphabet kommen würden. Stuttgart-Bad Cannstatt ist ein "Bad", aber "nur" ein Stadtteil von Stuttgart.

Comment: @tofro Baf Reichenhall hat so weit ich weiß hauptsächlich aufgrund der Sole den Titel. Zwar kann man in der Sole nicht schwimmen aber hat definitv etwas mit Wasser zu tun.

Comment: Meine preußische Mutter stammt aus Bad Kudowa, einer kleinen Stadt in Schlesien.